# Invoke JSF managed bean action on page load

Tags: jsf, action, onload, managed-bean

Is there a way to execute a JSF managed bean action when a page is loaded?

If that's relevant, I'm currently using JSF 1.2.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686821/execute-backing-bean-action-on-load/1695823#1695823

Comment: Not sure though, there is ambiguity in the question. As long as he don't explicitly state "download file on page load", or "fire new request on page load", or so, then the mentioned topic is not necessarily a dupe of this.

Comment: Correct answer is given here http://stackoverflow.com/a/1710413/362752

Answer (score 107, accepted):

### JSF 1.0 / 1.1

Just put the desired logic in the constructor of the request scoped bean associated with the JSF page.

```
public Bean() {
    // Do your stuff here.
}
```

### JSF 1.2 / 2.x

Use `@PostConstruct` annotated method on a request or view scoped bean. It will be executed after construction *and* initialization/setting of all managed properties and injected dependencies.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    // Do your stuff here.
}
```

This is strongly recommended over constructor in case you're using a bean management framework which uses proxies, such as CDI, because the constructor may not be called at the times you'd expect it.

### JSF 2.0 / 2.1

Alternatively, use `<f:event type="preRenderView">` in case you intend to initialize based on `<f:viewParam>` too, or when the bean is put in a broader scope than the view scope (which in turn indicates a design problem, but that aside). Otherwise, a `@PostConstruct` is perfectly fine too.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="foo" value="#{bean.foo}" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.onload}" />
</f:metadata>
```

```
public void onload() { 
    // Do your stuff here.
}
```

### JSF 2.2+

Alternatively, use `<f:viewAction>` in case you intend to initialize based on `<f:viewParam>` too, or when the bean is put in a broader scope than the view scope (which in turn indicates a design problem, but that aside). Otherwise, a `@PostConstruct` is perfectly fine too.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="foo" value="#{bean.foo}" />
    <f:viewAction action="#{bean.onload}" />
</f:metadata>
```

```
public void onload() { 
    // Do your stuff here.
}
```

Note that this can return a `String` navigation case if necessary. It will be interpreted as a redirect (so you do not need a `?faces-redirect=true` here).

```
public String onload() { 
    // Do your stuff here.
    // ...
    return "some.xhtml";
}
```

#### See also:

- [How do I process GET query string URL parameters in backing bean on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724428/how-do-i-process-get-query-string-url-parameters-in-backing-bean-on-page-load/)
- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-fviewparam-and-fviewaction-be-used-for/)
- [How to invoke a JSF managed bean on a HTML DOM event using native JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588327/how-to-invoke-a-jsf-managed-bean-on-a-html-dom-event-using-native-javascript) - in case you're actually interested in executing a bean action method during HTML DOM `load` event, not during page load.

Comment: your answer is great and fit to my need...
**But one question...**

In my D. constructor I am adding such a content that will be visible on view side (on the same jsp). In this case my jsp doesn't view this information on very first time. 
But if I reload a page that content is visible.

Can we handle this thing any way?

Comment: This answer will only work once if I have a session scope. Is there a better way to implement this for session scope bean?

Comment: @huahsin68, the answers provided are going to work as expected. As BalusC said, use the last two examples for beans that have a wider scope than **view**-scope.
For those curious about where to place the `f:metadata` information in a `ui:composition` page: Right after the `ui:composition` and **before** a possible `ui:define` or alike tags.

Comment: you should use "f:event"  instead of "f:viewAction", if you are using jsf 2.0+

Answer (score 14):

Another easy way is to use fire the method before the view is rendered. This is better than postConstruct because for sessionScope, postConstruct will fire only once every session. This will fire every time the page is loaded. This is ofcourse only for JSF 2.0 and not for JSF 1.2.

This is how to do it -

```
<html xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
      <f:metadata>
          <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{myController.onPageLoad}"/>
      </f:metadata>
</html>
```

And in the **myController.java**

```
 public void onPageLoad(){
    // Do something
 }
```

EDIT - Though this is not a solution for the question on this page, I add this just for people using higher versions of JSF.

JSF 2.2 has a new feature which performs this task using `viewAction`.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewAction action="#{myController.onPageLoad}" />
</f:metadata>
```

Answer (score 11):

@PostConstruct is run ONCE in first when Bean Created.
the  solution is create a Unused property and Do your Action in Getter method of this property 
and add this property to your .xhtml file like this :

```
<h:inputHidden  value="#{loginBean.loginStatus}"/>
```

and in your bean code:

```
public void setLoginStatus(String loginStatus) {
    this.loginStatus = loginStatus;
}

public String getLoginStatus()  {
    // Do your stuff here.
    return loginStatus;
}
```

Comment: So, you're using alone session scoped beans? That's a Bad Practice. Plus, your example is poor. Getters can be called more than once in bean's life and shouldn't be abused to execute business stuff. Just use a request scoped bean and do the job in constructor or `@PostConstruct`.

Answer (score 2):

Calling bean action from a `<p:remoteCommand>` will be a good idea, keep  attribute *autoRun="true"*
Example below

```
<p:remoteCommand autoRun="true" name="myRemoteCommand" action="#{bean.action}" partialSubmit="true" update=":form" />
```

Comment: Why is this a 'good idea' when the solutions above do not need an additional roundtrip.