# Passwords are not updated after a newly generated password is selected

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a password confirmation component. The user can enter the two passwords manually or can generate a pair. The generated passwords are shown in a select list. When a password is selected from the list, the two input passwords should be updated with this password. The problem is that the input password doesn't reflect the change after a password was selected.

#### password confirmation component:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:outputText value="#{eval.getString(name)}: #{mandatory ? '*' : ''}"/>   
    <h:panelGrid columns="3">               
        <h:column>
            <p:password id="psw1"
                value="#{eval.evaluateAsBean(beanName).password}" feedback="false"
                disabled="#{not enabled}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <p:commandButton value="#{label.create}" disabled="#{not enabled}"
                action="#{eval.evaluateAsBean(beanName).generate}"
                update="generated">
            </p:commandButton>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <p:selectOneMenu id="generated"
                disabled="#{not enabled}"
                value="#{eval.evaluateAsBean(beanName).selectedPassword}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{eval.evaluateAsBean(beanName).passwords}"
                    var="val" itemLabel="#{val}" itemValue="#{val}" />
                    <p:ajax listener="#{eval.evaluateAsBean(beanName).passwordChanged}"
                        update="psw1, psw2" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <p:password id="psw2"
                value="#{eval.evaluateAsBean(beanName).confirmedPassword}"
                feedback="false" disabled="#{not enabled}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <h:outputText value="" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <h:outputText value="" />
        </h:column>
    </h:panelGrid>
</ui:composition>
```

#### passwordChanged listener:

```
public void passwordChanged() {
    this.password = selectedPassword;
    this.confirmedPassword = selectedPassword;
}
```

#### Edit1

I have removed the update attribute from `p:ajax` and changed `passwordChanged` listener to:

```
public void passwordChanged() {
    this.password = selectedPassword;
    this.confirmedPassword = selectedPassword;
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("form:tabs:editorsGroup:editor:psw1");
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("form:tabs:editorsGroup:editor:psw2");
}
```

With Firebug the id of psw1 is: `form:tabs:9:editorsGroup:4:editor27:psw1`. Still doesn't work.

Comment: I have added `styleClass` for the two passwords and changed `update` to `update="@(.psw1) @(.psw2)"`. In the browser's console I get: `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .psw1) @(.psw2`

Comment: Can you confirm that `passwordChanged()` method is sucessfuly executed ?

Comment: Yes, I confirm that the `passwordChanged` method is executed successfully.

Comment: I am using PrimeFaces 3.4, Mojarra 2.0.9, Tomcat 7.0.30.

Comment: What is the _scope_ of your `managed bean` ?

Comment: The managed bean is session scoped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For obvious security reasons, the [`<p:password>`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/primefaces-p/password.html) (and [`<h:inputSecret>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/inputSecret.html)) do by default not redisplay the value from the model.

To turn off this security feature, set `redisplay="true"` (this applies to `<h:inputSecret>` as well).

```html
<p:password ... redisplay="true" />
```

#### See also:

- [Setting the value for jsf InputSecret during page load from the managed bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776263/setting-the-value-for-jsf-inputsecret-during-page-load-from-the-managed-bean/)