# Java URL problem

Tags: java, url, exe

A webpage contains a link to an executable (i.e. If we click on the link, the browser will download the file on your local machine).

Is there any way to achieve the same functionality with Java?

Thank you

Comment: how is it different from [reading binary data from an URL](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html)?

Comment: In a webpage generated by Java (in what framework?) or in a Java GUI (using what Framework?)?

Comment: @Nishant - that approach gives me the html source of the webpage but not the executable

Comment: well, you need provide the URL (URI) that points to the resource.. in your case the URL to the file. It would be something like `http://someforeignurl.com/some/download/location/filename.exe` -- Obviously you are giving it the shell page URL and expecting it to choose the download URL in the page and simulate `click` on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java's, [URL](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class to download a file, but it requires a little work. You will need to do the following:

1. Create the URL object point at the file
2. Call `openStream()` to get an `InputStream`
3. Open the file you want to write to (a [`FileOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html))
4. Read from the `InputStream` and write to the file, until there is no more data left to read
5. Close the input and output streams

It doesn't really matter what *type* of file you are downloading (the fact that it's an executable file is irrelevant) since the process is the same for any type of file.

**Update:** It sounds like what you actually want is to plug the URL of a *webpage* into the Java app, and have the Java app *find* the link in the page and then download that link. If that is the case, the wording of your question is very unclear, but here are the basic steps I would use:

1. First, use steps 1 and 2 above to get an `InputStream` for the page
2. Use something like [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) or [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to parse the HTML
3. Find the `<a>` element that you want and extract its `href` attribute to get the URL of the file you need to download (if it's a relative URL instead of absolute, you will need to resolve that URL against the URL of the original page)
4. Use the steps above to download that URL

Here's a slight shortcut, based on `jsoup` (which I've never used before, I'm just writing this from snippets stolen from their webpage). I've left out a lot of error checking, but hey, I usually charge for this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(pageUrl).get();
Element aElement = doc.getElementsByTag("a").first() // Obviously you may need to refine this
String newUrl = aElement.attr("abs:href"); // This is a piece of jsoup magic that ensures that the destination URL is absolute
// assert newUrl != null
URL fileUrl = new URL(newUrl);
String destPath = fileUrl.getPath();
int lastSlash = destPath.lastIndexOf('/');
if (lastSlash != -1) {
    destPath = destPath.substring(lastSlash);
}
// Assert that this is really a valid filename
// Now just download fileUrl and save it to destPath
```

The *proper* way to determine what the destination filename should be (unless you hardcode it) is actually to look for the `Content-Disposition` header, and look for the bit after `filename=`. In that case, you can't use `openStream()` on the URL, you will need to use `openConnection()` instead, to get a [`URLConnection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html). Then you can use `getInputStream()` to get your `InputStream` and `getRequestProperty("Content-Disposition")` to get the header to figure out your filename. In case that header is missing or malformed, you should then fall-back to using the method above to determine the destination filename.

Comment: I was able to download the file but when I double click it, the file opens as a blank windows terminal.

Comment: @Robin: Then something is wrong. Open the file in notepad to make sure that it's not actually an error message. Try checksumming the file downloaded with your web browser vs the Java app (`md5sum` or something like that) to see if they are identical

Comment: I am not passing the URL of the webpage that contains the downloadable link. I am passing the "downloadable link" itself in my java app (i.e. when I Paste the same link in the browser, it downloads the file for me).

Comment: @Robin: Your comment above "that approach gives me the html source of the webpage but not the executable" indicates otherwise

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. 
Here a simple example:

You can have a JSF(Java Server Faces) page, with a supporting backing bean that contains a method annotated with `@PostConstruct` This means that any action(for example downloading), will occur when the page is created.

There is already a question very similar already, have a look at: [Invoke JSF managed bean action on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451154/jsf-action-on-page-load)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using apache commons IO FileUtils

http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyURLToFile(java.net.URL, java.io.File)

**Edit:**

I was able to successfully download a zip file from source forge site (it is not empty), It did some thing like this

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils; 
public class Test 
{

 public static void main(String args[])
 {

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://sourceforge.net/projects/gallery/files/gallery3/3.0.2/gallery-3.0.2.zip/download");
        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, new File("test.zip"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
 }
```

I was able successfully download tomcat.exe too

URL url = new URL("http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-6/v6.0.16/bin/apache-tomcat-6.0.16.exe");

Comment: I was able to download the file but when I double click it, the file opens as a blank windows terminal.

Comment: I edited the answer with an example download. The file i downloaded was not empty