# Page On load event in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, onload, onload-event

I am trying to assign values to my dropdown  during  page load. I followed the way which is given in this link.

[Invoke JSF managed bean action on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451154/jsf-action-on-page-load/2451308#2451308)

As per the link, i have tried using both the annotation and constructor type.

but its an exception for me,

```
 SEVERE: An exception occurred
 javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Detected cyclic reference to managedBean loginBean
 Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: Detected cyclic reference to managedBean loginBean
```

I have just tried to call a function, in that annotated method or constructor,
that is,

```
     @PostConstruct
public void init()
{
receiveclass r=new receiveclass();
r.retrieve();

}
```

i cant able to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Detected cyclic reference to managedBean loginBean

You're injecting two different managed beans in *each other* as `@ManagedProperty`. This isn't allowed. It should be an one-way injection. Remove the `@ManagedProperty` referencing the one bean from the other bean.

Comment: ya i have used another bean class, but i dint use any managed property for it, "receiveclass" is my next bean class, wer i have used the retrieve() method to return the list of elements. And also i have another method in the same class for insertion of values while submit method is fired. Even i have tried after removing that managed bean, still it hits me the same error. "Detected cyclic reference to managedBean loginBean".

Comment: Perhaps you have still some `<managed-property>` noise left in `faces-config.xml`