# Listener on Omnifaces preInvokeAction/postInvokeAction not invoked without viewParam

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

I'm not 100% sure this isn't as designed, but it appears that a preInvokeAction listener in the view metadata is only invoked if a viewParam is present.

The following works:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="test" value="#{myForm.myValue}"/>
    <f:event type="preInvokeAction" listener="#{myController.initializeForm}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

But this does not:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event type="preInvokeAction" listener="#{myController.initializeForm}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

It may be that the invokeAction phase does not exist if there are no view parameters so it doesn't make sense, but I'm not familiar enough with the lifecycle at this level to know if that's the case or if this is just a miss.

A workaround is to just put in a bogus parameter.

Does anyone know if this is a bug or as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's indeed working as designed.

Those events are triggered during `INVOKE_APPLICATION` phase. When there are no view parameters discovered during `RESTORE_VIEW` phase, then JSF will immediately advance to `RENDER_RESPONSE` phase. All phases in between will be skipped: `APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES`, `PROCESS_VALIDATIONS`, `UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES` and `INVOKE_APPLICATION`.

The work around is indeed to declare a "dummy" `<f:viewParam>`, or better, use the JSF 2.2 provided `<f:viewAction>` instead as mentioned in [`InvokeActionEventListener` documentation](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/eventlisteners/InvokeActionEventListener).

```
<f:viewAction action="#{myController.initializeForm}" />
```

Do note that a `<f:viewParam>` does not necessarily require a bean property.

```
<f:viewParam name="test" />
```

It will implicitly be placed in request scope instead and be available as `#{test}`.

#### See also:

- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-fviewparam-and-fviewaction-be-used-for)
- [Invoke JSF managed bean action on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451154/invoke-jsf-managed-bean-action-on-page-load/)